# C++/C#/Win32_API - Delete Disk Volume/Partition - debug?

Tags: winapi, volume, disk

I'm trying to use [DeleteFileW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29) to remove a disk volume, which [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363983%28v=vs.85%29) is the function I should use.

I used WMI calls to Win32_Volume to get the device ID, which if i tack on a file it works correctly.

However, if I provide just the volume ID, I get an error 5, Access Denied.
I assume there is some preparatory work that needs to be done before I can delete it, but I cant figure out what.
I was thinking of attaching a debugger to DiskPart but since the DeleteFile function would be the last call I dont really know how to set a breakpoint to catch all the stuff before that. Also, I'm not awesome with the debugger.

So, the question is how do I delete a volume, or how do I setup the debugger to trap the deletion so I can read the previous function calls?

Comment: I guess the volume needs to be [locked or dismounted or somesuch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365729(v=vs.85).aspx) first.  A breakpoint on [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would probably yield the answer.

Comment: You might also require administrative privileges for this task.